# Image fading in windows store app c#

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am working on windows 8 store app in c#. I need to implement image fading in the app.

I tried to add border over it and increase thickness but could not work.

Can any one help me for how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0524d6/image-fadeing-in-metro-style-apps/

Answer (score 0):

By using visual state manager, you can achieve image fading animation. (I have not tried this piece of code, If you find any error please let me know :) );

```
<Button x:Name="btnFade" Content="Fade" Click="Button_Click" />
<Image x:Name="imageControl" width="500" height="500" Source="ms-appx:///dummy.jpg" />
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup >
            <VisualState x:Name="FadeInState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="imageControl"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1.0" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:5" 
                />

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="FadeOutState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="imageControl"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="0.5" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5"
         />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>                
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>

// code behind
private bool isFadeIn = false;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(isFadeIn == true)
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(gridControl, "FadeInState", true);
    else
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(gridControl, "FadeOutState", true);

    isFadeIn != isFadeIn;
}
```